# C# Uri produces different AbsoluteUri in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, encoding, uri

I discovered that C# Uri produces different absoluteUri when I run the same code from console application and IIS.

For example, running this following code:

```
new Uri("http://www.random.org/%D9%8A%D9%94").AbsoluteUri
```

in console application, I get same as input

`http://www.random.org/%D9%8A%D9%94`

in IIS env, I get

`http://www.random.org/%D8%A6`

When I decode those, it seems like they are referring to the same value, ئ , I do not understand running same code under IIS causes the difference.

Could you please help me making this consistent?

Comment: No, they are not the same value. The first one (console) is ئ like you mentioned, but the second one (IIS) is ئ. Notice the difference, the first one has two dots under it which the second one has no dots. I don't know what language that is (it can be Arabic, Farsi, etc), but those are two completely different letters. Anyway, I cannot believe that IIS is changing the letters, so double check that the input is really the same, because I think it's not or something else is happening.

Comment: Are the machine running the console app and the machine running IIS the same machine?

Comment: I ran them in the same machine with same input value.  I also notice the same issue when I run same binaries on EC2.  I guess there must be some IIS setting causing this, but I do not know what is causing this.

Comment: For some reason I'm reminded of the Punycode phishing bug that was recently in the news. https://threatpost.com/google-fixes-unicode-phishing-vulnerability-in-chrome-58-firefox-standing-pat/125099/ - Safari and Edge were not affected but other major browsers were. I placed that as a hyper link in a web app and it shows the full string `"http://www.random.org/%D9%8A%D9%94"` in Edge but the ئ character in Chrome.

Comment: I've done the same test and got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out!

I was applying iri parsing rule in IIS using the following in config file:

`<uri>
    <idn enabled="All" />
    <iriParsing enabled="true" />
</uri>`

I did not notice this because legacy code with this setting did not get affected by this.

Anyways, thank you very much for your time!